# Nginx rewrite перенаправление - помогите настроить

Tags: nginx, rewrite

На сайте есть директория /building/, соответственно есть целый раздел www.site.ru/building/ со мнжеством линков типа www.site.ru/building/[...]

Задача состоит в том чтобы перенести все линки вида www.site.ru/building/[...] в урлы вида www.site.ru/house/[...] 301ым редиректом, не меняя при этом имя каталога на сервере (останется building).

Я вижу эту задачу так: 1. нужна директива rewrite c permanent, 2. нужно чтобы по урлу вида www.site.ru/house/[...] nginx отдавал страницы вида www.site.ru/building/[...]

Но никак не могу заставить эти 2 правила работать вместе и последовательно. Получаю цикличный редирект. Много пробовал, последняя конструкция была такая

```
    location ^~ /house {
        rewrite ^/house(.*)$ /building$1 last; 
        break;
    }

    location ^~ /building {
        rewrite ^/building(.*)$ /house$1 permanent;
        break;
    }
```

Пожалуйста, попровьте

Answer (score 0):

```
location /building/ {
    rewrite ^/building(.*)$ /house$1 permanent;
}

location /house/ {
    root       /path/to/dir/building;
    try_files  $uri $uri/index.html @backend;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! @backend наверное тоже надо определить?

Comment: зависит от того как сейчас формируется контент. если по запросу к `/building/` сейчас отдаётся статичный контент то нужно заменить на `=404`, если контент динамический то в `@backend` нужно скопировать настройки обращения к беку

Comment: попробовал и так, и так, не хватает знаний и опыта наверное - не получается. Скажите, может есть какой-то более простой способ, или просто другой?

Comment: документацию прочёл? `root` поставил корректный?

Comment: документацию читаю, рут верный, проверил)
пробую через алиасы
 location ^~ /house {
     alias d:/localhost/www/building/;
 }
и для статики в виде картинок это работает, но как сделать чтобы и скрипты через алиас работали - не хватило фантазии.. может подскажете? чувствую там и нужен ваш @backend, но не могу применить сам

Comment: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/beginners_guide.html#proxy

Comment: спасибо! свой вопрос решил по-другому, а ваша ссылка будет полезна для общего развития

Comment: root явно нужно заменить на alias